# Exlude empty properties from Javascript ajax formData

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form-data

I have form that sends form data

The empty `fields[]` appear when there is no option selected.

Is there any way I can exclude the empty `fields[]` from sending via the **formData** in my Javascript?

**Sending Header Output**

```
fields[name]: name
fields[phone]: phone
fields[]: 
fields[]:
```

```js
$('body').on('submit', '#submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData(this);
  // logs what's the actual properties sent
  for (var prop of formData) console.log(prop);
    $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
  }).done(function(data) {
    //success
  }).fail(function() {
    //eror
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="submit">
  <select name="fields[name]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="phone">Phone</option>
  </select>

  <select name="fields[phone]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="phone">Phone</option>
  </select>
  <select name="fields[email]">
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="phone">Phone</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Set them to `disabled`, prior to calling `new FormData(this)`.

Comment: @CBroe Set what to disabled? The empty value comes from the select field that's not selected, there is not value for that select field

Comment: It's not possible to have such scenario in the html you provided. Can you post a real example? Otherwise it's not a problem to remove an entry from the FormData.

Comment: Any fields you do not want to show up on the submitted data. But as just mentioned, the HTML you have shown, does not appear to match what you say is happening. You should not be getting any _empty_ `fields[]` parameters with this, because the first option is by default considered the "selected" one.

Comment: @CBroe I have updated the form code. Can you check now

Comment: It is not possible to have `fields[]` empty even with this code ... you may have `fields[emai]:` empty per instance. What do you actually want to filter?

Comment: So go and set those select fields to `disabled`, that have an empty string as value at the time this gets submitted.

Comment: I'll correct your question code to add a log what's actually happens.

Comment: @Reflective the chosen phrasing isn't ideal here, I'm guessing they meant that they are getting `fields[name]=` when the "empty" option was selected, and rather avoid having `fields[name]` show up in the parameters at all then, rather than have it submitted with no value.

Comment: Done, execute you snippet to see the result in console. If you want to remove `fields[name]`  if empty, just say I want to do that.

Comment: @CBroe If he wants to remove all fields set to default empty option, we have to know that. It's pretty easy, but until now we are just guessing what's the idea behind the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are guessing that you want to clean up all form properties having empty value.
That's a way to do it, it could be more optimal but this is easier for understanding.

```js
$('body').on('submit', '#submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData(this);
  var formDataNonEmpty = new FormData();
  // add all non empy entries to formDataNonEmpty
  for (var prop of formData) if (prop[1]) formDataNonEmpty.append(prop[0], prop[1]);
  // logs what's the actual properties sent
  for (var prop of formDataNonEmpty) console.log(prop);
    $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: formDataNonEmpty,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
  }).done(function(data) {
    //success
  }).fail(function() {
    //eror
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="submit">
  <select name="fields[name]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="phone">Phone</option>
  </select>

  <select name="fields[phone]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="phone">Phone</option>
  </select>
  <select name="fields[email]">
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="phone">Phone</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that using `[]` is a bit tricky for PHP and you will actually have an associative array called `fields` with all keys there, so that's why you probably are experiencing these problems.

Comment: Yes I need the associative array in PHP. That's the way I want it. Thanks for your help.